# Looking at Null Space and Range of a Linear Map By Using Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume we are dealing with matrices in the fashion Axler handles it in Chapter 3. That is, a $m \times n$ matrix $A$ describes a linear map $T:V \rightarrow W$ from a basis $e_1,...,e_n$ of the domain $V$ to a basis $f_1,...,f_m$ of the codomain $W$.

Would it then be correct to say, that the number of non-zero rows, after using the Gaussian Elimination Algorithm on matrix A such that is in Reduced Row Echelon form, describes the dimension of $rangeT$?

Other than using the rank-nullity Theorem to subtract the number of non-zero rows from the the number of columns of the matrix, is there another way to quickly see what the dimension of the null space is?

Comment: Something about your description of the matrix of a linear transformation in the first paragraph doesn’t sound right. How does the zero matrix describe a linear map to a basis of the codomain? It seems like there’s something missing there.

Comment: @amd It could be that the map is not surjective, or in the zero case, have a range of 0. Perhaps I should change that to say "with basis $e_1...e_n$ of domain $V$" and "with basis $f_1,...,f_m$ of codomain $W$" instead of "from".

Comment: Perhaps “in terms of?”

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Dimension of row space is the same as dimension of the column space of a matrix and column space is nothing but $Range(T)$if you consider $T$ to be transformation having the given matrix as matrix representation with standard bases.Then the number of non zero rows in RREF given the row rank which is the same as dimension of linear transforamtion $T$'s range space.For nullity,you may column reduce the transformation matrix,then look at the number of $0$ columns.